# onClick event do more than one thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I currently have a link of the following format:

```
<a href='export.php' onClick='history.go(0)'>Export</a>
```

The export page returns a csv file so the main page that the link is clicked on is not refreshed, however I want this to happen.

How can I make the current page refresh after clicking the link?

Thanks.

Comment: You could start by posting some code.

Comment: Is the `history.go(0)` part your attempt, or is it for something else?

Comment: `window.location.reload(false)` will reload the page.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? Hit the export.php URL, then refresh the current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can try to guess at the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(event){
  $(".exportLink").click(function(event){

    window.location.reload();
    //export.php is called after this clickEvent completes, or you could $.get it at the start of this function
  });
});
</script>
```

html code I used:

```
<a href='export.php' class="exportLink">Export</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure he's using jQuery? I know it has that tag, but he didn't specifically say so in the question.

Comment: @alpha123 good point.  i just went by the tag.  it looks Neutralize took the time to tag it with jQuery and ajax.

Comment: Without more information it's probably safe to assume he is just because it has the tag and jQuery is so darn popular these days.

Comment: I am using jQuery, I added this function to my jQuery code and changed the link to the simple a href, but it did not work. Any ideas? EDIT: By not work I mean the page does not refresh, I also added a js alert but it doesn't appear this function is getting callde

Comment: @Neutralise I bet my selector is not picking up the link we want.  I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='export.php' onclick='history.go(0); window.location.href = window.location.href;'>Export</a>
```

Should do the trick.